# FreeMarker - How to use elements that have hypehns in the name

Tags: java, variables, freemarker

How can i use an element, which is not a top level element, that has hyphens in Freemarker templates

${variable.vars[“element-name”]}

doesnt seem to work. This gives me an error

```
"Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to a sequence+hash"
```

When i try to escape it as ${variable.element\-name}

```
Exception in thread "main" org.milyn.cdr.SmooksConfigurationException: Error invoking @Initialize method 'initialize' on class 'org.milyn.templating.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemplateProcessor'.
at org.milyn.cdr.annotation.Configurator.invoke(Configurator.java:457)
```

Comment: What is the error? Did you try escape character, ref: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html

Comment: yes, escaping the hyphen gives me an exception. I have updated my question with error messages

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300454/freemarker-vars-names-cant-contain-dashes

Comment: This is NOT A DUPLICATE! I have referred the question u posted above before asking this question. The .vars works for top level elements, not for sequence subvariables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of `variable.element\-name` without using the `\-` feature is `variable['element-name']`. (In general, in FreeMarker `foo.bar` is the same as `foo['bar']`.)

However, it's really strange that `\-` gives error. Maybe you have a really old FreeMarker dependency there? (Try what `${.version}` prints.) Also, aren't there cause exceptions in that stack trace? Seeing the root FreeMarker error message could help.

Comment: Thanks! [ ] worked. Just curious, which version supports escaping. I have 2.3.21

Comment: It's supported since FreeMarker 2.3.22. BTW, using an old version like that can cost you, as even if you don't use any new features, later FreeMarker versions tend to give more helpful error messages.

Comment: Thanks ddekany. I have updated my pom file to use the latest.